# Clone SQL Server database on the same server without .bak

Tags: sql-server, database

I would like to copy and rename a SQL Server database without creating a `.bak` file. Is it possible?

For example its works but use .bak file:

```
DECLARE @backupPath nvarchar(400);
DECLARE @sourceDb nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @sourceDb_log nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @destDb nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @destMdf nvarchar(100);
DECLARE @destLdf nvarchar(100);
DECLARE @sqlServerDbFolder nvarchar(100);

SET @sourceDb = 'db1'
SET @sourceDb_log = @sourceDb + '_log'
SET @backupPath = 'E:\tmp\' + sourceDb + '.bak' 
SET @sqlServerDbFolder = 'E:\DB SQL\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\'
SET @destDb = 'db2'
SET @destMdf = @sqlServerDbFolder + @destDb + '.mdf'
SET @destLdf = @sqlServerDbFolder + @destDb + '_log' + '.ldf'

BACKUP DATABASE @sourceDb TO DISK = @backupPath

RESTORE DATABASE @destDb FROM DISK = @backupPath
WITH REPLACE,
   MOVE @sourceDb     TO @destMdf,
   MOVE @sourceDb_log TO @destLdf
```

Comment: detach, rename, re-attach x 2 but this includes downtime - whats wrong with backup/restore?

Comment: @AlexK. You missed a copy step above.

Comment: @AlexK.  Client don't want create any extra file on disk.

Comment: You will create an extra file on disk anyway (two, actually), since the new database requires it. It sounds like you're being asked to jump through unreliable hoops for no other reason than to save on temporary disk space. Why is the clone being created? Another possible option (depending on what problem this is trying to solve) could be snapshots.

Comment: I needs clone for test app. I know that i will create file, but the client linger when see that i create .bak and deleted by:
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_delete_file 0,N'@Path' 
so i want to show 2 options.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio provides this feature( not included in Express edition). You can Right Click the database select **Tasks** and try **Copy Database**.

You can check this link for reference.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188664.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to simply create additional sQL Server container instances, with each running the same database.

Windocks supports all editions of SQL Server 2008 onward, on Windows 8, 10, Server 2012 and 2016.

*Disclosure: I am the Co-Founder of WinDocks*